# How to create Window.Forms.Form from Socket Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, sockets, applicationcontext

I'm writing a small app that will be the endpoint for NLog Network targets (Sending debug messages over TCP)  The app uses Sockets to create a server and accept connections.  This application is windowless and starts up in the System Tray using NotifyIcon and ApplicationContext.  The application listens on a port, when it receives it's first message from a unique endpoint it will create a new window and display it (These windows will contain the actual debug messages)  I've been able to get the window to display but it's displaying as if it's hung, I'm guessing it's because it is getting created from on of the invisible threads created by the Sockets.

How can I properly create a new Windows.Form from the test_ClientConnected event?

Here is the ApplicationContext Code

```
public NLApplicationContext()
    {
        NLServer test = new NLServer();
        test.ClientConnected += test_ClientConnected;
        test.Start();
    }

    void test_ClientConnected(object sender)
    {
        Form2 newForm = new Form2((NLClient)sender);
        newForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {newForm = new Form2((NLClient)sender);}));
        newForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { newForm.Show(); }));

        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        /*if (((NLClient)sender).testy.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ((NLClient)sender).testy.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(((NLClient)sender).testy.Show()));
            return;
        }*/
    }
```

Here is the programs entry point

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new NLApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delegate the UI work to a separate thread like this :

```
   void test_ClientConnected(object sender)
   {
     Thread displayFormThread = new Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart(DisplayForm));
     displayFormThread.Start(sender);
   }

   private void DisplayForm(object sender)
   {
    Form2 newForm = new Form2((NLClient)sender);
    newForm.Show();
   }
```

Comment: Hrmm...this does work, however I need it to be ran on the main UI thread because that is where I'm storing the form instance, List<Form2> of forms since there can potentially be a few connections.

Comment: Marked this as answer as it is the closest one.  You pointed me into the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea, instead of creating the form in the socket thread, move the code to create the form and show it into a method, then `Dispatcher.Invoke` the method to execute it on the UI thread.

Comment: Ok, do I create this Dispatcher?  The only references I find of it are for use in WPF, maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a different way that allowed me to create the form in the main UI thread.

NLApplicationContext

```
class NLApplicationContext : ApplicationContext 
{
    List<Form2> _connections;  // Temp storage for now
    SynchronizationContext testS;


    public NLApplicationContext()
    {
        testS = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        _connections = new List<Form2>();

        NLServer test = new NLServer();
        test.ClientConnected += test_ClientConnected;
        test.Start();
    }

    void test_ClientConnected(object sender)
    {
        testS.Post(DisplayForm, sender);
    }

    private void DisplayForm(object sender)
    {
        Form2 newForm = new Form2((NLClient)sender);
        newForm.Show();
        _connections.Add(newForm);  //Find better storage/sorting
    }
}
```

Using a SynchronizationContext allows me to post back to the thread that it was created on.